# css: link color in UL class does not override default color for div

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink

I have defined a div with the following:

```
#main-alt-2 a:link {color:#39c;}
#main-alt-2 a:visited {color:#39c;}
```

For a UL within this div I have defined this:

```
ul.menu a:link {
font-weight:bold;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;   
color:#323232;
}
```

All other properties within the ul.menu class work - except the color.
Very strange!

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If multiple CSS definitions pertain to the same HTML element, the [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) of the selectors is compared. To make rules with lower specificity take precedence, add `!important`:

```
ul.menu a:link {color: #323232 !important;}
```

Alternatively, you can make the second selector more specific.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much - all answers helped me clear out things, but the !important was the easiest solution ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Because of [css specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/), you will need to do it this way:

```
#main-alt-2 ul.menu a:link {
font-weight:bold;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;   
color:#323232;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#main-alt-2 a:link`, since it includes an id selector, is more [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) than `ul.menu a:link`

Make your selector [more specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity).

Comment: hmmm, the the UL is being used within a jquery menu which looks for classes, not id's, is there a way to make a class more specific? Or do i have to change everything to an ID?